# Docking a stackpanel at bottom, and add columndefinitions

Tags: wpf, xaml

My problem is visualized in the image "wrong.png"
I have created a stackpanel that should have 3 columns, and dock at the bottom, along with it contents, which in this case are 3 buttons. Looking at the "wrong.png", this is not going well for me.

I have added another image "desired.png", that shows what I want to achieve. 
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Here is code:

```
<Window x:Class="EnerMedit.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="499.88" Width="702">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Seavaro" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" />

        <Label Content="Date" Grid.Row="1" />
        <DatePicker Grid.Row="2" Name="datepicker" Background="Honeydew" />

        <Label Content="Note:" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0 10 0 0" />
        <RadioButton Content="Meditation" Name="mediNote" Margin="50 17 0 0" Grid.Row="3" />
        <RadioButton Content="Energy" Name="energyNote" Margin="150 17 0 0" Grid.Row="3" />
        <RadioButton Content="Both" Name="bothNoteButton" Margin="250 17 0 0" Grid.Row="3" Checked="bothNoteButton_Checked" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Background="Honeydew" />

        <Separator Width="auto" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0 20 0 20" Background="GreenYellow"/>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="6" MinHeight="150" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="Honeydew" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <CheckBox Content="Done" Name="doneCheck" Grid.Row="7" Margin="5 7 0 0" />

        <Label Content="Akana" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="18" Margin="10 0 0 0" />


        <CheckBox Content="Check all" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="200 7 0 0" Name="IsCheckedCheckAll" 
                  Checked="IsCheckedCheckAll_Checked" Unchecked="IsCheckedCheckAll_Checked" />


        <Label Content="Excercise 1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
        <CheckBox Name="Exc1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="200 7 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=IsCheckedCheckAll, Mode=OneWay}" />

        <Label Content="Excercise 2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
        <CheckBox Name="Exc2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Margin="200 7 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=IsCheckedCheckAll, Mode=OneWay}" />

        <Label Content="Excercise 3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
        <CheckBox Name="Exc3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Margin="200 7 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=IsCheckedCheckAll, Mode=OneWay}" />

        <Label Content="Excercise 4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
        <CheckBox Name="Exc4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Margin="200 7 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=IsCheckedCheckAll, Mode=OneWay}" />

        <Label Content="Excercise 5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" Margin="10 0 0 0" />
        <CheckBox Name="Exc5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Margin="200 07 0 0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=IsCheckedCheckAll, Mode=OneWay}" />                               
    </Grid>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>      

                <Button Content="Add" Name="SubmitButton" Grid.Column="0" Height="23" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=doneCheck, Path=IsChecked}" />
                <Button Content="Labaci recardo" Name="GetMedButton" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" />
                <Button Content="Supa recardo" Name="GetEnegButton" Grid.Column="2" />            
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: Try placing your `StackPanel` one level higher.

Comment: I tried that before I moved it out. The buttons will still float on top, but this time at the right side, and there will only be two columns, since there is already another columndefinition on that level

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove second `DockPanel` parent from your `StackPanel` and also you need to swap places of the resulting `StackPanel` and the `Grid`. Only then your main `DockPanel` will layout your elements as you expect it to do.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="800">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
        <Grid/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I edited the xaml code. Is this how you meant? It does not work. What happens, is that 3 more columns are added to the top right, and the buttons are still clustered in the first of the 3 columns

Comment: @user1960836 **NO, that's not how I meant.** First goes stackpanel, then grid, look closer to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the alignment, they are now shown horizontally. Only thing now, is that a third column is still created at the far right, and that's where the stackpanel is. I have edited the code. 
Thanks again

Comment: @user1960836 Can't you see where in **my example** are stackpanel and a grid located? In your code te grid goes first, and that is wrong, it should be the second child in the main dockpanel's content.